# How to combine two unrelated tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, cartesian-product, cross-join

There are two tables that are not related to each other(No foreign keys).
How to show them together in MySQL?

TABLE1

[image]

TABLE2

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Your desired result is a cross join, otherwise known as a Cartesian join, not a full outer join.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this too:

```
SELECT t2.date, t1.name
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table2 t2
```

Answer (score 6):

Try This..

```
 SELECT t2.date, t1.name FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 ORDER BY t1.name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simply

```
SELECT t2.date, t1.name FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: SELECT DATE, NAME FROM TABLE1, TABLE2

Answer (score 0):

None of those will work.

If you want to learn how to do this properly, I'd suggest you take a look at this 
http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

`CROSS JOIN` is not what you are looking for.

SQL will not be able to process this query. What I suggest you do is to get both record sets with two different queries and then sort them by the field you want, using PHP/Python/C or whatever the code your app is based on. Just don't leave that to the MySQL server because it can't.

Comment: "Just don't leave that to the MySQL server because it can't." - I don't think I understand this.  Cross Join is exactly what he needs, correct?