# MySQL selecting from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

im trying to select data from multiple tables, now i am fine with doing it with two tables as i do a query like so:

```
$myquery = sql_query(
    "SELECT a.object_title, a.published_by, b.userid
     FROM table1 AS a 
     JOIN table2 AS b ON (a.published_by = b.userid)"
);
```

But see now, i want to select data from a third table, however this third table does not have relationship such as primary key between the first two tables, so i simply want to just pull data from it and form any sort of link with a "JOIN".

How would simply add the third to this query?

Thanks

Comment: Write a seperate query? Since it's not related, you don't need to write it in the above query.

Comment: I cant do this, as it will overwrite my first query as i need them both in the same section.

Comment: You could simply do this: `SELECT a.object_title, a.published_by, b.userid, c.id, c.field
     FROM table1 AS a, table3 as c` Just keep in mind that this will preform a Cartesian product with this table.

Comment: can you tell me what you mean by cartesian product?

Comment: You should also have a look at this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) that I wrote which covers a lot of this sort of thing in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CROSS JOIN` :

```
$myquery = sql_query(
    "SELECT a.object_title, a.published_by, b.userid, c.whatever
     FROM table1 AS a 
     JOIN table2 AS b ON (a.published_by = b.userid)
     CROSS JOIN table3 AS c"
);
```

I used [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630227/how-to-combinefull-join-two-unrelated-tables-in-mysql) to find the idea.

More infos [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php).

Answer (score 0):

Add within you query a Left Join.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myquery = sql_query(
            "SELECT a.object_title, a.published_by, b.userid, c.column_name
             FROM Table1 AS a 
             JOIN Table2 AS b ON (a.published_by = b.userid)
             CROSS JOIN Table3 AS c"
);
```